# LINQ to retrieve first matching item, or a blank value for each item in a list

Tags: linq

I am having some trouble with a linq query

```
var matches = from po in purchaseOrders
          from poItem in po.Items
          where TestMatch(poItem)
          select new Item(poItem);
```

purchaseOrders is a List
Each PurchaseOrder contains a List

What I need for a result, is the first poItem that matches (based on the result of `TestMatch(poItem)`) in each purchase order, OR a blank Item object.

So that in the end matches.Count == purchaseOrders.Count

Currently, I only get items that match in a PO, and I'm not sure how to ensure I only get ONE item per PO.  And I don't know how to ensure if there is no match, that I get a blank Item for that PO.

Comment: Could you include the `TestMatch` function also

Comment: @Magnus, it's not needed to answer this, and Jon Skeet has already found the solution.

Comment: yes, but I think some kind of left join with whatever is inside the TestMatch might give you better performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
 var matches = from po in purchaseOrders
               let poItem = po.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => TestMatch(item))
               select new { PO = po, 
                            Item = poItem == null ? null : new Item(poItem) };
```

With C# 4 you can use a method group conversion for the argument to FirstOrDefault:

```
 var matches = from po in purchaseOrders
               let poItem = po.Items.FirstOrDefault(TestMatch(item)
               select new { PO = po, 
                            Item = poItem == null ? null : new Item(poItem) };
```

Comment: I never even thought of moving the condition in to a let clause.  Excellent!

Comment: `po.Items.Where(poItem => TestMatch(poItem)).FirstOrDefault()` can be written as `po.Items.FirstOrDefault(TestMatch)`

Comment: @Firo: Agreed about using the predicated form. (Edited.) Whether you can use a method group conversion or not may depend on the version of the C# compiler you're using though. Type inference improved in C# 4.

Comment: Actually had to leave it as `.Where`, then use `.FirstOrDefault`, as I needed an `.OrderBy` in between the two as well.